# sysctl disable IPv6 autoconf

Tags: debian, ipv6, sysctl, ovh, debian-buster

I'm trying to setup IPv6 on my OVH server using [their guide](https://docs.ovh.com/gb/en/dedicated/network-ipv6/#objective).

In the article they recommend to

> disable IPv6 autoconf and router advertising to prevent known issues
> You can do so by adding the following lines to your `sysctl.conf` file, which is located in `/etc/sysctl.conf`:
> `net.IPv6.conf.all.autoconf=0`
> `net.IPv6.conf.all.accept_ra=0`
> Once this has been done, you can apply those rules by executing the following command: `sh sysctl -p`

I added those parameters to my the sysctl config like described. When trying to apply the config using `sysctl -p` I get the following error(s):

```
sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/net/IPv6/conf/all/autoconf: No such file or directory  
sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/net/IPv6/conf/all/accept_ra: No such file or directory
```

I'm on Debian 10 with a recent kernel:

```
# cat /proc/version
Linux version 4.19.0-9-amd64 (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) (gcc version 8.3.0 (Debian 8.3.0-6)) #1 SMP Debian 4.19.118-2+deb10u1 (2020-06-07)
# cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="10"
VERSION="10 (buster)"
VERSION_CODENAME=buster
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a typo. `ipv6` should be in lowercase.

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.autoconf=0
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra=0
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, do you have any good resource on how to switch to systemd-networkd?

Comment: See https://wiki.debian.org/SystemdNetworkd and [The modern network configuration without GUI](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch05.en.html#_the_modern_network_configuration_without_gui) in the Debian manual.

Comment: Much appreciated. However I don't think it will be possible to incorporate that with the OVH network, they are doing a lot of autoconfig stuff.